# Python Kivy DLL load failed on Using ArcGIS ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-10.4

I am running Kivy and Python properly when it is only Kivy as

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

but when I add ArcGIS Python library called ArcPy like below

```
import arcpy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') 

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

I am getting following error:

Message File Name   Line    Position

> Traceback
>            5
>         C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py    327
>         C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py 219
>         C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics__init__.py  89
>       init kivy.graphics.instructions (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:14640)  kivy\graphics\vbo.pxd   7
>       init kivy.graphics.vbo (kivy\graphics\vbo.c:5482) kivy\graphics\compiler.pxd  1
>       init kivy.graphics.compiler (kivy\graphics\compiler.c:2983)   kivy\graphics\shader.pxd    5
>       init kivy.graphics.shader (kivy\graphics\shader.c:11990)  kivy\graphics\texture.pxd   3
>       init kivy.graphics.texture (kivy\graphics\texture.c:31800)    kivy\graphics\fbo.pxd   5
>       init kivy.graphics.fbo (kivy\graphics\fbo.c:7683) kivy\graphics\fbo.pyx   84       ImportError: DLL
>   load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: What is `kivy`?  I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Cross posted on [so] - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838679/python-kivy-dll-load-failed-on-using-arcgis-arcpy - Please [don't cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Without knowing what `kivy` is or does, I feel this question may be more suited to [so].  I am voting to close as Off-Topic.  If you feel that it is more on-topic here please [edit] your question with further details.

Comment: Hi Midavalo, Kivy is open source ,Cross-platform Python Framework for NUI Development you can find more on here https://kivy.org/#home